# using google cloud API to get bills

Tags: google-cloud-platform

can we use any google API which can provide information about the total charges spent using Google Cloud Platform? i have tried few APIs (detail shown in code).

API 1:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var cloudbilling = google.cloudbilling('v1');
google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, authClient) {
if (err) {
console.log('Authentication failed because of ', err);
return;
}

if (authClient.createScopedRequired && 
authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
authClient = authClient.createScoped(scopes);
 }
 var request = {
  name: "projects/<your-project-id>", 
// Auth client
  auth: authClient
};
 cloudbilling.projects.getBillingInfo(request, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
}  else {
   console.log(result);
 }
   });
  });
```

What i am getting in json (about billing information) is:

```
data:
   { name: 'projects/<your-project-name>/billingInfo',
     projectId: '<project-Id>',
 billingAccountName: 'billingAccounts/<your-billing-id>',
 billingEnabled: true } 
   }
```

Now i have tried other APIs too, but they are also not providing the total charges spent!. Is there a way i can find the bills?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The info in the actuall bills is not (or at least not yet) available in any of the [Cloud Billing APIs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis).

But there are other options for accessing the data via other paths:

- you can [Export Billing Data to a File](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file) (in GCS):

> To access a detailed breakdown of your charges, you can export your
>   daily usage and cost estimates automatically to a CSV or JSON file
>   stored in a [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/index) bucket you specify. You can then
>   access the data via the Cloud Storage API, CLI tool, or [Google Cloud
>   Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

- you can [Export Billing Data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery):

> Tools for monitoring, analyzing and optimizing cost have become an
>   important part of managing development. Billing export to
>   [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) enables you to export your daily usage and cost
>   estimates automatically throughout the day to a BigQuery dataset you
>   specify. You can then access your billing data from BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the billing data from Google Cloud Platform:

- Export Billing Data to BigQuery
- Export Billing Data to a File

For BigQuery:

1. Enable billing export to BigQuery
2. Create a BigQuery Client
3. Run a query to get the billing data query to get daily cost:

For File:

1. Enable billing export to a file
2. Write a code to download an object from a bucket
3. Iterate through a downloaded file and perform the summation of "cost" property

You can refer to the script that I have created [here](https://github.com/rnmulchandani/gcp/blob/master/gcp_billing.py)

Hope this helps :).