# How to export Appengine Usage History using CLI

Tags: google-app-engine

Using GUI, I can export from Appengine->Quota->UsageHistory->Export Last 90 Day To CSV.

But I want to export automatically with jenkins.
How to export Appengine Usage History using CLI.
(or something, such as Billing->Billing Export)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis), but it doesn't yet have support for the ops you're seeking. Maybe in the future.

But it's possible to have GAE automatically export the info for you, rather than doing it on-demand via jenkins. With this configured you can, in jenkins, just pull the already exported data instead of actually performing the export. See [using google cloud API to get bills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664989/using-google-cloud-api-to-get-bills/48676174#48676174).

There's also an open feature request for a [Quota statistics API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35876330), possibly of interest.